# Postgres and sqlalchemy password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, docker-volume

Attempting to import data into Postgres via a SQLalchemy python script. Postgres is on docker and I am using docker volume for data storage.
I have:

1. ChatGPT to confirm the compose file
2. Lint the Python file
3. Googled the error
4. Reviewed the link in the error, it simply points out that the error is not with SQLalchemy.
5. Confirm the use exists on the docker container
6. Reviewed similar errors on stackoverflow
7. Also posted the issue in slack group

Running the following command:

```
python ingestData.py \
  --user=postgres \
  --password=postgres \
  --host=localhost \
  --port=5432 \
  --db=ny_taxi \
  --table_name=yellow_taxi \
  --url=https://github.com/DataTalksClub/nyc-tlc-data/releases/download/yellow/yellow_tripdata_2021-01.csv.gz
```

Receiving the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8) <--- this link is of little help :-(
blackitalian@blackitalian:/mnt/d/ds_projects/de_zoomcamp/docker_sql$ docker exec -it postgres bash
2037c7983657:/# id postgres
uid=70(postgres) gid=70(postgres) groups=70(postgres),70(postgres) <--- the user has been built
```

docker-compose:

```
services:
  pgdatabase:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    user: "0:0"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=ny_taxi
    volumes:
      - "pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - pg-network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=blackitalian@gmail.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=root
    volumes:
      - "pg-admin:/var/lib/pgadmin"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - pg-network

networks:
  pg-network:
    name: pg-network

volumes:
  pg-data: 
    name: ingest_pgdata
  pg-admin:
    name: ingest_pgadmin
```

ingestData.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import os
import argparse
from time import time
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def main(params):
    """Import data to Postgres"""
    user = params.user
    password = params.password
    host = params.host
    port = params.port
    db = params.db
    table_name = params.table_name
    url = params.url

    # the backup files are gzipped, and it's important to keep the correct extension
    # for pandas to be able to open the file
    if url.endswith('.csv.gz'):
        csv_name = 'output.csv.gz'
    else:
        csv_name = 'output.csv'

    os.system(f"wget {url} -O {csv_name}")

    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db}')

    df_iter = pd.read_csv(csv_name, iterator=True, chunksize=100000)

    df = next(df_iter)

    df.tpep_pickup_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_pickup_datetime)
    df.tpep_dropoff_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_dropoff_datetime)

    df.head(n=0).to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='replace')

    df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append')


    while True:

        try:
            t_start = time()

            df = next(df_iter)

            df.tpep_pickup_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_pickup_datetime)
            df.tpep_dropoff_datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.tpep_dropoff_datetime)

            df.to_sql(name=table_name, con=engine, if_exists='append')

            t_end = time()

            print(f'inserted another chunk, took {t_end - t_start} second')

        except StopIteration:
            print("Finished ingesting data into the postgres database")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Ingest CSV data to Postgres')

    parser.add_argument('--user', required=True, help='user name for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--password', required=True, help='password for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--host', required=True, help='host for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--port', required=True, help='port for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--db', required=True, help='database name for postgres')
    parser.add_argument('--table_name', required=True,
                        help='name of the table where we will write the results to')
    parser.add_argument('--url', required=True, help='url of the csv file')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args)
```

Comment: What information is already in Postgres before running the script?

Comment: It's just the Postgres container. This script is the only data I am pushing to it.

Comment: if for some reason you already had a different Postgres container with a different username and password using the same volume mount, your new container will not use your new username password, it will use the old one, clear the volume `pg-data` or use a new volume instead of `pg-data` for the same path and then see if that changes things

Comment: I deleted the volumes and did a rebuild, but I am still getting the error. This is the only postgres, I deleted all other containers and volumes. However, it is now running after I walked away from it for a few hours. I have no idea why it's suddenly working.